# How can a rebel leader rile up citizens while satiating an angry government?

Tags: government, cities

A small rebel force has provoked the beginning of an uprising, and a small portion of a city's people has been stirred to anger against the government. No attempts to infiltrate or overthrow the government have been made, until the rebel force bombs a government shuttle dock.

The government retaliates by torturing and killing various people in order to find their way to the rebel "base". The government had no knowledge as to whether or not some of these people were guilty.

Naturally, this turns many more citizens to anger against the government - now 50% of the population is angry at the government, but still no rioting. Then, however, the leader of the rebel alliance is captured and put into prison. The common folk had varying degrees of knowledge that this leader was "in charge" of the rebellion, and many of them respected or admired him as a person.

The government puts out many advertisements and public service announcements intended to discredit the leader. This scares some of the mildly angry people into submission, but infuriates some others. Small rioting begins to occur (beer bottles thrown at government building windows, officials are assaulted, etc).

Then, the government releases the leader from prison temporarily, on a sort of parole or probation. The government intends for him to make a statement in front of the city, saying something along the lines of "I was mistaken in my actions. Lay down your weapons. We don't need an uprising/rebellion," with the intention of calming them.

Naturally, the leader does *not* want to calm the citizens, but to stir them up to even more anger against the government. He makes a statement in front of the people, bashing on the government for their actions and justifying his. The government puts him back in prison and severely beats/tortures him.

After three weeks of the leader being imprisoned again, the people have lost a small bit of faith in him (and the rebellion itself). The leader is then, once again, temporarily released, but this time he is forced to make an immediate statement on live TV, with the entire city watching.

The leader wants to make a statement that will both:

- Satiate the government (convince the officials that the leader no longer wants an uprising and regrets his actions to start one)
- Rile up the citizens (convince the citizens that the government is unjust and deserves to be overthrown)

He has about an hour to think of a speech, that will be around five minutes. If he fails to satiate the government he will be killed or exiled. If he fails to rile up the people he will be shunned by the community.

**What can he say?** I can't come up with anything sufficient for the life of me. (I'm not looking for an exact speech, just the general direction it should go in.)

Comment: Maybe he could lie and say he saw some hidden operations go down when they was in prison, and maybe use that as leverage for the rebellion. Either that or the could somehow convice them that government is infearior, that either there is something better out there or that the leader are the better government and that they should follow them.

Comment: @Unhappymarshmellow Indeed he could, but remember that the goal is to rile up the people *while keeping the government satisfied*.

Comment: Then how about he lies again just that he saw the people in the government doing good things for the populous, and if he can, bring some "proof" to show he is still trustworthy despite being in jail and then sent back.

Comment: @user535733 That's true. I simplified the story a bit (a lot) for the question, but I might need to add more detail about the government. The government is intentionally somewhat useless, but I didn't include much information at all about them.

Comment: Sounds like Martin Luther King to me

Comment: You're asking about the actions of an individual (the rebel leader) not about building a fictional world. Such questions are off topic on this site,

Answer (score 2):

one of the most complicated tasks out there would be, covering something you want to be uncovered. In your question, you want your rebel leader to say something positive about the government, and the same time, make the rebels rile up.

I would be using the statement, "There are always two sides of a coin"

Some people would think otherwise on everything that you said, some people will believe you, It is how the listening person receive your message, a bit complicated aye? but that's how it works.

So how would he do it.

He should think of the most wrong act that government had done (e.g. that government might have killed millions) then tell the people that the government has done a wonderful thing about it, explaining that the genocide is something positive. It's telling something awfully devastating that it is good, that MAY spark a full size rebellion, and it may not, it really depends on how the listener receives his message.